# lodash take v javascript slice performance

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of length 100,000,000

When `max` is nearly at the end of the array, this takes about 8 seconds:

```
return _.take(numbers, max)
```

This takes about 1 second:

```
return numbers.slice(0, max)
```

Why the massive performance difference? thx

Comment: Because `Array#slice` is native and `_.take` is not. Native functions are very optimized by engines. `_.take` is most likely calling `Array#slice` behind the scenes but with some other code for validating the function parameters, ...

Comment: With 100M integers, both ways crash my node process with an out of memory error. However with 10M integers, both ways seem to be equally fast. You need to provide more info about your environment I think.

Comment: you need to run your code with this node flag --max-old-space-size=12288 and have a decent pc

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Are you sure that `some other code for validating the function parameters` is the cause of such a massive performance drop?

Comment: I would assume that `take` would validate its parameters once then perform its magic.

Comment: @customcommander [`_.take`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/take.js) calls [`_.slice`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/slice.js). `_.slice` doesn't call the optimized native `Array#slice` function, it instead cuts elements from the array itself by using a `while` loop. A `while` loop is surely no match for native code which is probably using some super fast lowlevel stuff like memory copying or something.

Comment: I believe you. I was simply referring to your previous statement in which you were implying that validating parameters was causing such a gap in the performance. That didn't seem convincing to me. Not using native method is most likely the cause.

Comment: @customcommander I didn't notice that OP's code is calling `_.take` once. I thought it was being called 100M times, in which case the simple code used for validating the parameters will make a difference.

Comment: sorry should have clarified take is only called once, my bad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lodash uses its own implementation of `slice` (in the bundled version called `baseSlice`) array method which you can [see here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.11/lodash.js#L4051).

One of the main premises of lodash is browser compatibility which they achieve in most of the cases by having `lodash` version of various methods.

Good example is `_.take` as well as `_.slice/_.tail/_.chunk/_.drop/_.dropRight/_.initial` etc methods which all under the cover utilize the `baseSlice` method and do not rely on the native `Array.slice`

So if you compare `native` vs `lodash` you would find native winning consistently, but that is not what makes lodash shine ... at-least prior **ES6** that is.

Comment: thanks, another gem of an answer - was massively impressed by your answer the other day :)

Comment: Thanks! Glad I can help.